# FusionTablesLayer where clause not working & geometry not displaying google maps javascript api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In my head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window._initHomeMap = function(){
    if( document.getElementById('map') !== null ){
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(30,0),
            zoom: 2,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            scrollwheel: false,
            draggable: false,
        });

        var world_geometry = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            query: {
                select: 'geometry',
                from: '1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk',
                where: 'ISO_2DIGIT IN ("US", "CA", "AF")',
            },
            heatmap: {
              enabled: false
            },
            suppressInfoWindows: true,
            map: map,
            options: {
              styleId: 2,
              templateId: 2
            },
            styles: [{ //included because geometry not showing up
                polygonOptions: {
                    fillColor: '#FF0000',
                    fillOpacity: 0.4
                }
            }],
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

In my body:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

Just before the closing body tag:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBrRJwJFfNCdVLJwa6yhR8UBZR1m2A018Q&amp;callback=window._initHomeMap"></script>`

The Result: [image: Screencap]

I want to pull from a [FusionTable](https://fusiontables.google.com/data?docid=1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk&pli=1#rows:id=1) that has country geometry in it and show country boundaries on the Google map. But for some reason the geometry isn't showing (unless I use that styles property) and the where clause in the query isn't working. I've been scouring SO and elsewhere and I can't find what I'm doing wrong. Been at this for hours. Any help/guidance appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I generate the query using the FusionTables UI, I get (which works for me):

```
  query: {
    select: 'geometry',
    from: '1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk',
    where: "ISO_2DIGIT IN ('US', 'CA', 'AF')",
  },
```

(Notice the swapped `"` & `'` in the `where:`)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/o6mbz2t1/)

[image: screen shot]

**code snippet:**

```js
window._initHomeMap = function() {
  if (document.getElementById('map') !== null) {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(30, 0),
      zoom: 2,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      scrollwheel: false,
      draggable: false,
    });

    var world_geometry = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      query: {
        select: 'geometry',
        from: '1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk',
        where: "ISO_2DIGIT IN ('US', 'CA', 'AF')",
      },
      heatmap: {
        enabled: false
      },
      suppressInfoWindows: true,
      map: map,
      options: {
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
      },
      styles: [{ //included because geometry not showing up
        polygonOptions: {
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.4
        }
      }],
    });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", window._initHomeMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: i've been able to get a codepen version of this working as well but on my localhost & staging server i still get the screenshot i posted in the OP. Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried clearing out the cache on your browser?

Comment: Yes this is taken directly from my site and i've tried different derivatives of it. Same result.

Comment: The version in your question or the version in my answer?  (They are not the same)

Comment: Actually the thing that was preventing this from working was that I was using the callback param in the URL instead of listening via the google.maps.event object. Thanks for help!

Comment: That shouldn't be required (use an onload listener rather than the API callback), but it should give you an error in the javascript console indicating the issue (which is not the issue described in this question, best I can tell).